# PHP compare two arrays and return only unique array values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Finishing up an open source Domain Registrar plugin and having a few troubles with determining when a change has been made.

```
$saved = array(
        array( 'domain' => 'mydomain.com', 'record' => 'A', 'value' => '8.8.8.8' ),
        array( 'domain' => 'mydomain.com', 'record' => 'NS', 'value' => 'ns1.mydomain.com' )
    );

$new = array(
        array( 'domain' => 'mydomain.com', 'record' => 'A', 'value' => '4.4.4.4' ),
        array( 'domain' => 'mydomain.com', 'record' => 'NS', 'value' => 'ns1.mydomain.com' ),
        array( 'domain' => 'sub.mydomain.com', 'record' => 'A', 'value' => '1.2.3.4' ),
    );
```

`$saved` is the values already saved at the domain registrar, and is only being used for comparison.

`$new` is the array returned from application that processed the form on the website.

I need to somehow only return arrays that have values that were updated or that do not already exist/match from `$saved`.

Basically the return array i'm looking for would be:

```
array(
    array( 'domain' => 'mydomain.com', 'record' => 'A', 'value' => '4.4.4.4' )
    array( 'domain' => 'sub.mydomain.com', 'record' => 'A', 'value' => '1.2.3.4' ),
);
```

Because in `$saved` the `value` was updated from `8.8.8.8` to `4.4.4.4`, and the `sub.mydomain.com` did not match any array from `$saved` meaning it's a new entry.

Using `array_intersect` I was able to get it to return the array that had it's values updated, but unfortunately it still includes the arrays that matched as well.  If I could somehow have those removed that would be exactly what I need.

Here's a demo:
http://glot.io/php/529b0c6d2fd16fe221f86bb521155384

Maybe use `array_uintersect` with a callback to check if the arrays match and unset?  Looking for some help as i'm stuck on this now.

Thanks!!

Comment: What about `$diff = array_diff($new, array_intersect($new, $saved));`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in this case you could flatten them thru serializing, them map, them finally `array_dif()`

```
$result = array_map('unserialize', array_diff(array_map('serialize', $new), array_map('serialize', $saved)));
```

Should produce based on example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [domain] => mydomain.com
            [record] => A
            [value] => 4.4.4.4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [domain] => sub.mydomain.com
            [record] => A
            [value] => 1.2.3.4
        )

)
```

Comment: Perfect!  Works just like needed and simple without adding function!  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

[array_udiff](http://php.net/array-udiff) should work here.

Something along the lines of the following comparison function as a custom callback should do the trick:

```
$saved = array(
        array( 'domain' => 'mydomain.com', 'record' => 'A', 'value' => '8.8.8.8' ),
        array( 'domain' => 'mydomain.com', 'record' => 'NS', 'value' => 'ns1.mydomain.com' )
    );

$new = array(
        array( 'domain' => 'mydomain.com', 'record' => 'A', 'value' => '4.4.4.4' ),
        array( 'domain' => 'mydomain.com', 'record' => 'NS', 'value' => 'ns1.mydomain.com' ),
        array( 'domain' => 'sub.mydomain.com', 'record' => 'A', 'value' => '1.2.3.4' ),
    );


function cmpr($a, $b) {
    foreach($a as $k=>$v) {
        if ($b[$k] !== $v)
            return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

var_dump(array_udiff($new, $saved, 'cmpr'));
```

The output should look something like what you expected:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["domain"]=>
    string(12) "mydomain.com"
    ["record"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["value"]=>
    string(7) "4.4.4.4"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["domain"]=>
    string(16) "sub.mydomain.com"
    ["record"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["value"]=>
    string(7) "1.2.3.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, this does in fact work, but i'm going to use the serialize one to keep it simple and without adding another function.  Thank you for your help though, greatly appreciated and your solution does work!

Comment: Sure, no problem. Though you should probably know that the PHP serializer is really slow. This doesn't simplify your problem it sort of complicates a bit actually. Also, you can use a closure if you don't want the function defined in the global scope.